# Finding the x-y coordinate

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a word search code. And so far I can now find the direction of all the words in a given grid. Now my problem is how to find its x-y coordinates of the first letter ONLY.

I have a snippet of the code here:

```
words=['hello','hola','hella','heya','heyo','hill','halo','hall','hail','hay','hale','holy']
rows= ['eahaehh','allehoh','gohloau','rhelloy','iayoyiu','iiaelah','hlhallo']
row_length=len(rows[0])
column_length=len(rows)

for row_number, row in enumerate(rows):
    final_word = next((word for word in words if word in row), None)
    if final_word:
        print(f"{final_word} right")

for row_number, row in enumerate(rows):
    candidate = ''.join(reversed(row))
    final_word = next((word for word in words if word in candidate), None)
    if final_word:
        print(f"{final_word} left")

negative_slopes=[[rows[column_length-1-q][p-q]
        for q in range(min(p, column_length-1), max(0, p-row_length+1)-1, -1)]
       for p in range(column_length+row_length-1)]

positive_slopes=[[rows[p - q][q]
             for q in range(max(p-column_length+1,0), min(p+1, row_length))]
            for p in range(column_length + row_length - 1)]

for word in negative_slopes:
    candidate=''.join(word)
    final_word = next((word for word in words if word in candidate), None)
    if final_word:
        print(f"{final_word} down-right")

for word in positive_slopes:
    candidate=''.join(reversed(word))
    final_word = next((word for word in words if word in candidate), None)
    if final_word:
        print(f"{final_word} down-left")
```

So obviously it just prints the final word and its direction. I tried putting a for loop nested inside each loop but that just basically ruins the entire code. So I tried to make a separate code that theoretically would find the coordinates of the first letter I just don't know how I would integrate it into my existing code. Here is the possible solution:

```
for row_number, row in enumerate(rows):
    for column_number, letter in enumerate(row):
        for word in words:
                if word[0]==letter: 
                    coordinates.append[column_number, row_number]
```

So I would have two dictionaries with this elements:

```
coordinates={'hello': (2, 6), 'hola': (2, 6), 'hella': (2, 6), 'heya': (2, 6), 'heyo': (2, 6), 'hill': (2, 6), 'halo': (2, 6), 'hall': (2, 6), 'hail': (2, 6), 'hay': (2, 6), 'hale': (2, 6), 'holy': (2, 6)}

solution={'hello': 'right', 'hall': 'right', 'hella': 'left', 'hale': 'left', 'hail': 'down', 'heya': 'down', 'holy': 'down', 'hola': 'up', 'hay': 'down-right', 'hill': 'up-left', 'heyo': 'up-right', 'halo': 'down-left'}
```

Well this was a good idea at first but I forgot to take account that it would just literally find the letter and give its coordinates. As you can see the coordinates are all (2,6) since this is the coordinates that h first appears.

I was hoping to have an output of:

`word (x,y) direction`

How could I solve this problem. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Don't search again for the word.  Rather, stick in a local variable to hold the coordinates of your starting position.  *If* you find the word, then return that position as well.

In a little more detail ...

Your triple-nested loop (`for row_number ... for column_number ... for words`) is (1) overkill and (2) prone to error.  Just add code to save the position as soon as you find the word.  For instance:

```
for row_number, row in enumerate(rows):
    final_word = next((word for word in words if word in row), None)
    if final_word:
        print(f"{final_word} right")
        ^ YOU ARE HERE ...
```

... at this ^ point, you already have the `row_number`.  The `index` method will give you the column.

For each of the other directions, you construct an artificial "row" of letters to search.  That construction is a simple linear transformation; simply apply the reverse computation for the indices, and you'll again have the needed `(x, y)` coordinates.  Work through the math for that.  For instance, if you've constructed a "row" that starts at (0, 5) and goes down the south-west diagonal; and then you find your word starting at position `2` of *that* "row"; then how do you compute the coordinates of that starting letter?

The derivation is left as an exercise for the reader.  :-)

Comment: wait what do you mean by 'don't search again for the word'. What part do I have to remove exactly. Sorry am pretty much new in python